# Assembly register vs CPU register

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

As a CS beginner, I know that the CPU has some hardware called register that used to store temporary variables. But I also see x86 assembly code has the "register" conception like %EAX, %ECX. Wondering what's the difference here, or are they the same thing or do they have any relationships?

Comment: Its the same thing.  %eax  et al are x86 incarnation of CPU registers.

Comment: These are the same thing.  On high performance processors, the processor may have many more than just these registers, but they are just implementation details and not visible to the programmer.  As far as the programmer is concerned, `eax` and friends are the registers of the machine.

Comment: Practically the entire purpose of programming in assembly language is to have direct access to the CPU registers and related hardware features.

Answer (score 0):

They were once the same thing, and in a more primitive CPU architecture they are still the same thing.

x86 now does register renaming and the CPU actually has a lot more registers than it would appear. On the other hand, you may write code as though that were not true. If you can tell the difference by any means other than execution speed, the CPU is buggy.

Comment: It's useful to distinguish here between architecture (the on-paper ISA, which defines things like EAX), and the *micro*-architecture which is how the CPU actually implements the ISA.  (e.g. by [renaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming) onto a larger register file).  So I would have said "more primitive microarchitecture".  Also, high performance implementations exist for most modern mainstream (not DSP / microcontroller) ISAs, all using out-of-order execution with register renaming.  x86 is not unique and was not the first.

Comment: Or possibly you're making the point that Intel P6-family had a retirement register file with a single slot for each architectural register, with renaming done separately with values stored right in the ROB entries.  (P4 and Sandybridge-family (https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/), and AMD, have all used a separate physical register file.)